# ¿Cómo agregar caracteres mediante javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Tengo una ventana de configuración y en dicha ventana tengo una textfield oculto que me obtiene la ruta de una imagen y se la manda a la otra ventana de php donde se deberá almacenar. Esto ya lo realiza, el problema es que la ruta se toma con diagonales como es obvio, pero estas diagonales se toman de diferente manera y no se guardan en la base de datos.

Aquí se obtiene la ruta de mi imagen

```
                    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                    $("#file-1").change(function (e) {
                        var file, img;


                        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                            img = new Image();
                            img.onload = function () {
                                var ruta = $('#file-1').val();
                                $('#longitud').text(this.width);
                                $('#alto').text(this.height);
                                $('#ruta').val(ruta);
                            };
                            img.onerror = function () {
                                alert("Archivo no valido: " + file.type);
                            };
                            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


                        }

                    });
```

En esta parte del código se procesa dicha ruta

```
$imagen=$_POST["ruta"];

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("proyecto_terror");

        mysql_query("update configuracion set MenuFC= '$MenuFC',MenuLC='$MenuLC',MenuLT='$MenuLT',MenuLE='$MenuLE',MenuIma='$imagen' WHERE fk_usuario = '$id'");
```

Lo que me gustaría poder hacer es agregarle una diagonal en cada posición de la ruta donde se requiera para así poder generar una contrabarra y que almacene la ruta original.

Así la almacena actualmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la imagen de lo que me envía la Url desde javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Actualmente te almacena en la base de datos algo así `C:fake.jpg`. Y tu necesitas algo así: `C:\fake.jpg`, ¿No? ¿Es necesario hacerlo en Javascript? ¿Habría problema si te digo como hacerlo en PHP?

Comment: ¿Qué valor te arroja la URL *antes* de que la envíes al servidor (puedes obtenerlo con `console.log`), y qué valor recibe en la variable $imagen? ¿Puedes compartirlas por favor? Sospecharía de que se alteró la URL en PHP, no tanto en JavaScript

Comment: oye hoose esta bien no hay problema si la solución es en php, es que crei que seria mas fácil en javascript

Comment: oye jesus Franco ya actualice mi post

Comment: @David Relacionada: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127) <-- leelo para ver  problemas serios de seguridad que tenés en el código

Comment: muchas gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 1):

Como dices que no hay problema si te paso la solución en PHP. Te digo como 'guardar' una imagen en la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

Supongamos que tenemos nuestro código HTML de la siguiente manera en un formulario POST.

```
<input type="file" name="foto" required>
```

Entonces cuando mandemos el input por POST en PHP sería de la siguiente manera. Te dejo la explicación en los comentarios del código:

```
    //PROCESO DE FOTO
    /* $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] nos dará el directorio donde se encuentra el documento.
   Es decir que http://localhost/tiendaWeb/productos/insertar.php nos dará como resultado
   /tiendaWeb/productos/insertar.php

   basename nos devuelve el nombre base de los directorios del documento, en este caso insertar.php

   str_replace nos sirve para reemplazar cadenas por otras
   str_replace ("insertar.php", "", "insertar.php") | str_replace ("$palabraABuscarEnCadena", "$laReemplazamos", "$cadena")
   Con str_replace le estamos diciendo que busque exactamente la cadena/palabra insertar.php y que la modifique a nada (""), en la cadena "insertar.php"

   Almacenando en la variable $directory_self = /tiendaWeb/productos
   */
   $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

   /*
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] nos dará el directorio raíz desde donde se ejecuta el AppServ
   Nos dara como resultado C:/AppServ/www/ concatenando la variable $directory_self y la carpeta donde subiremos las fotos, en este caso yo la llame uploads pero ponganle otro nombre.
   Al final $uploadsDirectory da la siguiente cadena C:/AppServ/www/tiendaWeb/productos/uploads
  */
     $uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$directory_self.'uploads/';

  // Almacenamos en la variable now la hora.
     $now = time();

  /*
  Creamos un ciclo while y verificamos si el archivo existe con file_exists y dentro de file_exists, añadimos la variable donde se almacenara la foto ($uploadsDirectory), concatenamos la hora ($now), añadimos el caracter -
y por último obtenemos el name que tiene el input file de tu formulario y el nombre del archivo mediante ['name']
 Y nos arrojara:
                            C:/AppServ/www/tiendaWeb/productos/uploads/1460665367-ledwatch.jpg

 C:/AppServ/www/tiendaWeb/productos/uploads/ <- $uploadsDirectory| 1460665367 <- $now - <- Referencia al '-' ledwatch.jpg <- $_FILES['foto']['name'] (Así se llama la imagen que subi)
 */
   while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES['foto']['name'])){ $now++; }

 /*
  move_uploaded_file nos permite "copiar" la imagen de una ubicación a la ubicación que queremos.
*/
   @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $uploadFilename);

 /*
  Iguale la variable $uploadFileName con $foto para hacer referencia en el INSERT
*/
   $foto = $uploadFilename;
   $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (cve_producto, producto, descripcion, costo, cantidad, proveedor, rfc, foto) VALUES ('$clave','$producto','$descripcion','$costo','$cantidad','$proveedor', '$rfc','$foto')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar base64 para evitar inyección SQL y otros problemas de seguridad con eso que quieres hacer,
Un simple ejemplo:

```
    // subes el valor encriptado a la base de datos
   $upload = base64_encode( isset($_POST['ruta']) ? $_POST['ruta'] : "" );

 // true si esta establecido ruta de lo contrario base64 retornara false.

   // y lo puedes desencriptar
   $dbresult = "cGF0aDpcZm9sZGVyDGlsZS5pbmk=";

   $path = base64_decode($dbresult);
   // salida:
      path:\folderile.ini
```

Ahora si no me equivoco ese problema es por que el charset de tu base de datos no soporta ese tipo de datos con símbolos o puede que necesites usar otro tipo de consulta.